# Use CURL to make a GET request with query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, curl, console, query-string

I am making the following curl request from the console to test one of my REST API

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost/api/v1/user/search.json?search_model[first_name]=abc&auth_token=xyzf"
```

But it is failing with the following error

```
curl: (3) [globbing] error: bad range specification after pos 58
```

I wrapped the endpoint with `"` because `&` is used to execute the precious command in console. What else am i missing? Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
steve>curl --help | grep glob
 -g, --globoff       Disable URL sequences and ranges using {} and []
```

Try adding -g.